# Understanding floating point precision range

Tags: floating-point

Though reading numerous posts here regarding floating point, I couldn't find answer to this basic question:

What is the calculation that leads to this fact:

> The IEEE 754 standard specifies a binary32 as having [...]  6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision

i.e., what calculation enable us to determine that the minimum precision is 6 decimal digits, and the maximum precision is 9?
This also interests me regarding IEEE 754 double-precision floating point (15-17 significant decimal digits).

Comment: It is explained excellently by Rick Regan here http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/

Comment: This is generally done using `10log(2^24)` [where 24 is the number of bits in the significand], which is slightly below 7. So you get at least 6 digits (in total, no matter where the decimal point is). This is a little complicated by the fact that not all numbers in a range of `[1.0*10^x .. 10.0*10^x)` have the same exponent, but the log thing can be seen as a rule of thumb.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Log base 10 of 2^24 is slightly *above* 7.

Comment: @RickRegan: Hmm... you are right. Many take the top bit off, because it is always one anyway, and then it is slightly below 7. Also, the mentioned exponent issue plays a role. Someone (can't remember who or where) examined this extensively by checking all ranges of floats, and he came to a conclusion that 6 digits is the minimum.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Many do take the top bit off, but that is wrong. And that 'someone' you say who 'examined this extensively' is probably Bruce Dawson or me.

Comment: @RickRegan: that could be, i.e. that it was one of you two. Anyway, the `10log` thing is a simple rule of thumb, a coarse approximation, no more than an indication. I know that the real issue is a little more complicated.