# Convert.ChangeType messing up return value

Tags: c#, floating-point

We have a validation in place for years in our code base which was doing just fine until now. The issue started happening when values up to four decimal places started coming into the picture. To visualize review the following line of code;

```
//upto 3 decimal, returns just fine
//temp is equal to 1000.003
var temp = System.Convert.ChangeType("1000.003", TypeCode.Single);

//Test for values upto 4 decimals
//Iteration:1 
//Supplied 1000.0001 Return 1000.00012
var temp1 = System.Convert.ChangeType("1000.0001", TypeCode.Single);

//Iteration:2
//Supplied 1000.0004 Return 1000.00043
var temp2 = System.Convert.ChangeType("1000.0004", TypeCode.Single);

//Iteration:3
//Supplied 1000.0007 Return 1000.00067
var temp3 = System.Convert.ChangeType("1000.0007", TypeCode.Single);
```

Why is it acting this way? And another thing is if I change the `TypeCode` to `double` then precision is saved, why?

Comment: [A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting the return values you say you are.  When I run `System.Convert.ChangeType("1000.0001", TypeCode.Single);` in LinqPad, the return value I get is `1000`, not `1000.00012`.  Are you doing anything else with the return value of that method?  **Update:**  I had to use a string format of "R" to get `1000.00012`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I pasted the code which I have written in console application in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, Target .Net Framework is 4.6.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['float' vs. 'double' precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx#Precision):

> A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

You're running into cases where the number you pass in can't be represented exactly as a `Single`, so it gives you the closest `Single` value it can. If the decimal representation must be preserved exactly then `Decimal` is a more appropriate type.

Note that the fact that there are four digits after the decimal is irrelevant. You'd have the same issue with numbers like `100,000,010`

Comment: Thanks for the response, may be a silly question but I will ask, single's max value is 3.40282347E+38, yet precision is up to 7 decimals? I think I am confused :(

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla I'd suggest reading up more on floating point numbers, since I suspect your mental model of how they work is slightly incorrect. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891228/meaning-of-precision-vs-range-of-double-types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045787/how-many-decimal-places-does-the-primitive-float-and-double-support https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195975/understanding-floating-point-precision-range

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla The _precision_ and _scale_ are stored separately. Meaning you can represent 1,234,567,000 but not 1,234,567,899. The first has 7 digits of precision (7 significant digits) while the second has 10.

Comment: The MSDN page really does say that. Shudder.

Comment: What do you think it should say @EricPostpischil?

Comment: @mjwills: It ought to avoid discussing `Single` has having decimal digits at all, except in very precise statements such as asserting that a numeral with seven significant decimal digits can be converted to a `Single` and back to the same number of digits without change. The `Single` format does not “have” or “maintain” any decimal digits at all. That is not a correct description of either its internal representation or its value. Readers should be guided away from thinking of binary floating-point using decimal ideas.

Comment: It doesn't say it has digits in terms of internal representation. It says it has `digits of precision`. You may view that text, on its own, as problematic @EricPostpischil (I would disagree, but let's put that to one side) - but I'd suggest you need to read the statement **in context** (of the entirety of the rest of the page). _One of the tensions when writing docs is who to target - the person who knows it already or the person who doesn't? I think they made the right trade-off here - trying to upskill the person who doesn't know it already._

Comment: @mjwills: Even interpreted as seven “digits of precision,” it is wrong. After assigning `Single value = .9f;`, the value in the `Single` will not be 9 in the first decimal place. So a `Single` cannot be relied on to maintain seven decimal digits of precision.

Comment: That is clearly discussed in the link @EricPostpischil - search for `2/10`. Hence my point about context. You need to read the entire page.

Comment: @mjwills: Bad text in one place is not corrected by good text in another. The error in saying that a `Single` maintains a maximum of nine digits internally is not fixed by context—it is just wrong. And that text you point to about “2/10” is also wrong. It says “In this case, the floating-point value provides an imprecise representation of the number that it represents.” This is a misconception that floating-point numbers represent numbers approximately. The IEEE 754 standard is clear that a floating-point datum represents one specific number exactly; they are not approximations.…

Comment: Thanks for the discussion @EricPostpischil. Given your passion on the subject, perhaps consider writing another answer incorporating your thoughts?

Comment: … As the standard defines floating-point arithmetic, the **operations** return results that are exact mathematical values rounded to the nearest representable values. This distinction is crucial to understanding floating-point data and arithmetic and to using it correctly. Misunderstanding floating-point objects as representing numbers approximately leads to incorrect conclusions about how the arithmetic behaves.